# Сменить background-color onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css, javascript-events

Почему myFunction() позволяет показать и спрятать блок, а myFunction2() присваивает цвет, но не возвращает прозрачность.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.display === "inline-block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "inline-block";
  }
}

function myFunction2() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mobile-menu-wrap");
  if (x.style.backgroundColor === "#300") {
    x.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
  } else {
    x.style.backgroundColor = "#300";
  }
}
```

```css
#show-hide {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #300;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#mobile-menu-wrap {
  display: block background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="mobile-menu-wrap">
  <div id="show-hide" onclick="myFunction();myFunction2();"></div>
  <div style="display: none;" id="myDIV">
    <a href="/">Home</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: выведи в консоль `console.log(x.style.backgroundColor);`  и всё поймешь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После выполнения `x.style.backgroundColor = "#300"`
`x.style.backgroundColor` становится равным `"rgb(51, 0, 0)"`.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.display === "inline-block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "inline-block";
  }
}

function myFunction2() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mobile-menu-wrap");     
  console.log(x.style.backgroundColor);
  if (x.style.backgroundColor === "rgb(51, 0, 0)") {
    x.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
  } else {
    x.style.backgroundColor = "#300";
  }
}
```

```css
#show-hide {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #300;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#mobile-menu-wrap {
  display: block background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="mobile-menu-wrap">
  <div id="show-hide" onclick="myFunction();myFunction2();"></div>
  <div style="display: none;" id="myDIV">
    <a href="/">Home</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

x.style.backgroundColor === '#330000'
может быть так нужно?

Comment: Нет, не так нужно

Comment: никакого отличия